# MVC version of JQGrid: setting default values for edit fields (dropdown, text, and checkbox)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

How do you set default values in edit/search fields in JQGrid (using the MVC version)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setting Defaults for DropDown**

```
new JQGridColumn
{ 
   DataField = "myField",
   DataType = typeof(string),
   Editable = true,
   EditType = EditType.DropDown,
   EditFieldAttributes = new List<JQGridEditFieldAttribute>()
   {                                     
      new JQGridEditFieldAttribute(){ Name = "defaultValue", Value = "myDefaultValue"},
   },
},
```

**Setting Defaults for TextBox**

```
new JQGridColumn
{ 
   DataField = "myField",
   DataType = typeof(string),
   Editable = true,
   EditFieldAttributes = new List<JQGridEditFieldAttribute>()
   {                                     
      new JQGridEditFieldAttribute(){ Name = "value", Value = "myDefaultValue"},
   },
},
```

**Defaulting CheckBox to Checked**

```
new JQGridColumn
{ 
   DataField = "myField",
   DataType = typeof(bool),
   Editable = true,
   EditType.CheckBox,
   EditFieldAttributes = new List<JQGridEditFieldAttribute>()
   {                                     
     new JQGridEditFieldAttribute(){ Name = "checked", Value = "checked"},
   },
},
```